# Prism.Unity.Forms injecting INavigationService to ViewModel constructor

Tags: xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

**Code Snippet 1:**

```
    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this._navigationService = navigationService;
    }
```

**Code snippet 2:**

```
    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navService)
    {
        this._navigationService = navService;
    }
```

Can anyone explain why `Code Snippet 1` works but `Code Snippet 2` throws exception (`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`)?

**The only difference between two is, parameter name in the constructor.**

*P.S. I am using Prism 6.2.0*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each DI container works slightly differently, however the `INavigationService` is a unique service within Prism.Forms. Prism is very big about decoupling your Views and ViewModels. That said the INavigationService in reality needs to know about the View in order to function properly. For that reason the instance of the `INavigationService` that is injected into the ViewModel is actually constructed through a factory method called `ConfigureViewModelLocator` in the PrismApplication, and then injected into the ViewModel.

It is for this reason that it is a named service and in the case of Unity why it has to be the first parameter in the constructor. See the [`ConfigureViewModelLocator`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms/PrismApplication.cs#L25) method for a more complete understanding of what is going on here.

Comment: This is exactly why.  To clarify, it doesn't have to be the first parameter, but it does have to be named exactly "navigationService" to work.

Comment: Seems you cannot inject into a View constructor either. It just fails to navigate. I have a simple page with no view model (app settings), it just fails to load if I try to inject INavigationService into the view constructor, as though it is newing it up and only calling the default constructor of the view.

Comment: @SeanAnderson You should not be navigating from the Views code behind.

Comment: @DanS. I know, I know. The page was/is all raw navigation so I didnt have a ViewModel for it originally. This behavior isn't called out anywhere, not that the Prism Forms documentation is to be mistaken as complete.

Comment: @SeanAnderson while we have removed the names requirement for ViewModels it is a specially constructed service that cannot and never will be supported for Views particularly as it would create a circular reference in which we require context of what the page is that you are navigating from. You’re of course welcome to do it wrong just don’t confuse that as a blessing or an indication you’ll be supported by the Prism team in any way.

Comment: @DanS. Not married to "doing it wrong," it just fails silently for undocumented reasons if you don't adhere to the assumptions in Prism (that you just relayed). I'm moving away from a custom, blog-pilfered navigation service to Prism, so running into little surprises. Otherwise a smooth and pleasant upgrade.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by fails silently... if there is an exception encountered in the Navigation that exception is returned to you in the INavigationResult and the result has a bool to indicate if it was successful or not.